# Filling region with a pattern

Tags: plotting, filling, textures

I'm trying to fill the region to the left of a vertical line with a pattern (`Diagonal` is enough for my purposes) and a different pattern to the right.

I've tried

```
ListPlot[{{18, 0}, {18, 30}}, Filling -> {1->{Top},1-> {Axis}}, 
 FillingStyle -> HatchFilling[], Joined -> True]
```

I get the message that neither `Top`nor `Axis` are valid Filling specifications, so part of the problem may be the fact that it's a vertical line. However, I get the same message if I try a slanted line

```
ListPlot[{{0, 0}, {18, 30}}, Filling -> {1 -> {Top}, 1 -> {Axis}}, 
 FillingStyle -> HatchFilling[], Joined -> True]
```

I imagine this is due to the fact that I only have two points in the ListPlot so I've also tried a different approach

```
 Graphics[{LightYellow, HalfPlane[{18, 0}, {18, 30}, {0, 0}]}, 
  Axes -> True, PlotRange -> {{0, 30}, {0, 30}}],
```

using a color rather than `HatchFilling[]` (which is my primary goal) because this is not a graphic primitive. This results in a blank graph and I'm confused as to why it doesn't work.

**Edit**
Upon further research, I've discovered that `HatchFilling` was introduced in version 12.1 while I'm using 12.0.0.0. I'm guessing that using patterns was possible prior to 12.1 (though probably required a bit more work). I'd appreciate any pointers to achieve my desired result without using `HatchFilling`.

Answer (score 7):

To fill the region under a curve, you need a curve that spans the x-PlotRange. E.g.:

```
ListLinePlot[{{{0, 30}, {18, 30}}, {{18, 0}, {18, 30}}, {{18, 
    30}, {35, 30}}}, Filling -> {{1 -> Axis}, {3 -> Axis}}, 
 FillingStyle -> {1 -> HatchFilling[-0.5], 3 -> HatchFilling[.5]}, 
 Joined -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: I've tried your proposed solution. I get filling not with patterns but with colours. I'm using Mathematica 12.0.0.0. Is it possible that ```HatchFilling``` was introduced in a latter version?

Comment: I think it was introduced in 12.1. I'll have to look for another solution

Answer (score 4):

**Edit**

```
data1 = {{0, 30}, {18, 30}};
data2 = {{18, 30}, {35, 30}};
newdata1 = Join[{{data1[[1, 1]], 0}}, data1, {{data1[[-1, 1]], 0}}];
newdata2 = Join[{{data2[[1, 1]], 0}}, data2, {{data2[[-1, 1]], 0}}];
fig[color_, angle_] := 
  Graphics[{color, 
    Table[InfiniteLine[{0, i}, AngleVector[angle]], {i, -2, 2, .05}]},
    PlotRange -> 1/2];
RegionPlot[{WindingPolygon[newdata1], WindingPolygon[newdata2]}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Texture[fig[Cyan, π/4]], 
   Texture[fig[Brown, -π/4]]}, BoundaryStyle -> None, 
 Epilog -> {Thickness[Large], Green, Line[{{18, 0}, {18, 30}}]}, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Here we use `Texture` and `WindingPolygon`.Maybe work in 12.0 version.

```
data = Table[{x, Sin[x]}, {x, 1, 8, 0.01}];
newdata = Join[{{data[[1, 1]], 0}}, data, {{data[[-1, 1]], 0}}];
angle = π/4;
fig = Graphics[
   Table[InfiniteLine[{0, i}, AngleVector[angle]], {i, -2, 2, .05}], 
   PlotRange -> 1/2];
RegionPlot[WindingPolygon[newdata], PlotStyle -> Texture[fig], 
 TextureCoordinateFunction -> ({2 #1, 2 #2} &)]
```

[image]

[image]